# Creating online android app with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, webserver

I want to create an online app between 2 players and join and find each other like a simple question-answer app and more than a thousand people can join the server. It's better to use firebase or create a web server as a host ... (I'm so interesting  about web servers)i will mark this correct for those who can answer thanks

Comment: any advice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice between Firebase and a web-server would be solely based on the needs of your application and on your skills.

Firebase provides features of a real-time database, authentication, storage, notifications, hosting etc. without any server-side coding and other options which makes it really easy to integrate with your app. However, if the app requirements are above the free usage quota of Firebase, you would have to pay up for the services. Since you need the server for more than a thousand people, it would be most likely that you would have to pay for Firebase services. Also, if the app complexity increases, Firebase may or may not be able to cater to the needs of the app.

On the other hand, a custom server would have options just enough for your app. However, creating a custom server could be hard, depending on your skills. It would also require more maintenance than Firebase.

Comment: so you suggest firebase ok I'll use it on my app thanks

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!